# Using Cypress: how to locate a newly created list in trello

Tags: cypress

In my test I am creating a new card in a Trello list. After the card has been created I then attempt to open this new card so I can do some more tests on it.

The problem I am having is that the locator the Selector Playground tool is giving me includes a sequential card # that is created when the card is created. Since I don't know what that # will be until I run the test, I can't write the cy.get with the correct # in there.

So I am guessing there is a smarter way to find this specific element, trying to figure that out.

Here is my code so far

```
// add a card to list 1
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .list > .card-composer-container > .open-card-composer > .js-add-a-card')
        .click()

        cy.get('.list-card-composer-textarea')
        .type('new card');

        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .nch-button')
        .click();

// open new card - need to figure out how to select this guy because the 21 number changes each time, even if I delete the card then recreate it

cy.get('[href="/c/5VzF7JFb/21-new-card"] > .list-card-details > .list-card-title').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Didn't know about cy.contains, or forgot about it. This works.

```
cy.contains('new card')
```